# Nginx configure SSL error "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH"

Tags: ssl, nginx

I configure my nginx for a https service, but it does not work. The chrome showed error "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH". It's seemed like that the browser want an ssl protocol that my nginx can't support? However, I followed the official document from where I got the CA to configure my nginx.conf file as below.

I run `curl https://ltp-cloud.com` and get error "curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure"

There is my nginx.conf:

```

```html
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name ltp-cloud.com;
    ssl on;
    root html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert/214234087720826.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert/214234087720826.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    location / {
        root html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}

}
```

My Nginx version is below and I checked that "--with-http_ssl_module" option is on.

```html
➜  nginx nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Request your help on this.
Thanks!

Comment: Does your access with curl connects to your server or to something else? Because from here access to ltp-cloud.com results in a certificate for wangzhan.360.com if SNI is not used and an error if SNI is used (and curl uses SNI). Thus the problem might be outside of nginx, i.e. wrong DNS settings or similar.

Comment: You nginx version is way too old. Please update it to the latest version.

Comment: Here is the config on wangzhan.360.com is these two lines: `@ A 117.xxx.xxx.11 600`
`@ TXT 20xx...xxmf 600`. And I have updated my nginx version to 1.12 but still have this problem.